# Safari causing unexpected div offset

Tags: html, safari

I have a page at http://zackelx.com/50/SO_a9.html  with a BUY button.  When you go to the page with Chrome and click the button a checkout form comes up where the blue Pay button is located correctly under the last input field:

[image]

But if you go to the page with Safari you get:[image]

I'm using Safari 5.1.7 on a Windows 7 machine.

The HTML for the checkout form around the Pay button is:

```
  <label id="instr">instr</label>
      <input type="text" id="instructions" placeholder="size, color, etc."/><br />

      <div class="button">
          <div class="inner">
              <button type="submit">
                  <span class="pay_amount">123</span>
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
```

The browser should place div.button underneath the input#instructions element, and Chrome does that.  But Safari places it a few pixels down from the top of the input element, as if div.button had a style something like `position:relative; top:-20px`.   But there's nothing like that, and using the Safari inspector I don't see anything that would keep div.button from being placed completely under input#instructions.

Does anyone see what's going on here?

whole code for the pop up form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="checkout_form" autocomplete="off">

      <label id="state">state</label>
      <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_state" class="state generic" placeholder="NY" autocomplete="" required=""><br>

      <label id="cc">cc#</label>
      <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_cc_number" class="cc-number" x-autocompletetype="cc-number" required=""><br>

      <label id="exp">exp</label>
      <input type="text" id="checkout_form_cc_exp" class="cc-exp" x-autocompletetype="cc-exp" placeholder="MM/YY" required="" maxlength="9">

      <label id="CVC">cvc</label>
      <input type="text" class="cc-cvc" x-autocompletetype="cc-csc" placeholder="CVC" required="" maxlength="4" autocomplete=""><br>

      <label id="instr">instr</label>
      <input type="text" id="instructions" placeholder="black"><br>

      <div class="button">
           <div class="inner">
             <button type="submit">
                   <span class="pay_amount">Pay $12.00</span>
             </button>
           </div>
      </div>

      <img id="padlock" src="https://zackel.com/images/padlock_30.jpg" alt="padlock">
      <img id="creditcards" src="https://zackel.com/images/creditcards.jpg" alt="creditcards">
      <div id="validation"></div>
</form>
```

css:

```
#checkout_form {
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    left: 43px;
    width: 224px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post a complete code example including your CSS.

Comment: The CSS is in external .css files.  If you look at the page with the Safari or Chrome inspectors, though, you can see the styles that get applied.

Comment: I'm not visiting your site (sorry). You  need to post the code in your question because without it, once it's fixed, your question will lose all value.

Comment: I tried reducing the problem to everything I thought was relevant and put it into a jsFiddle, but it worked!  So something pretty subtle is going on, that may need the whole page to fail.  I understand what you're saying, but people can see the problem here, and they can see the basic HTML.  If the answer were something like,"Safari has a bug that adds a margin whenever you have ......."  that would be a very useful answer and maintain the question's value. But suit yourself.

Comment: I'm not 100% for sure but I think `#checkout_form button` is the problem here.

Comment: Safari 8 Mac OS X 10.10 - all is ok. Check Safari for Mac only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing Safari-specific rendering issues related to the positioning used.

#### Solution:

You don't need to change any of the HTML, just overwrite the CSS by placing the following CSS at the end of your stylesheet:

I tested it in Safari (Windows) v5.1.7, and it [seems to work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkpSl.png).

For the `#checkout_form` element, `top: auto`/`left: auto` are used to reset the positioning that was previously being used. I gave the element a width of `100%`, and used padding to position the elements. `box-sizing: border-box` is used to include the `padding` in the element's width calculations. The vendor prefixes are used to support older browsers (`-webkit-` in Safari's case).

For the parent button wrapper element and the credit card image, `margin: 10px 0 0 50px` was essentially used to displace the element and centered it below the field elements. It's worth pointing out that `text-align: center` on the parent `#checkout_form` element was being used to center the elements.

I presume that you wanted the `#padlock` element hidden, thus `display: none`.

```
#checkout_form {
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 38px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
#checkout_form .button,
img#creditcards {
  margin: 10px 0 0 50px;
}
#checkout_form .button button {
  position: static;
}
#checkout_form img#padlock {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Josh, yours is the only solution that worked for me.  Breaking it down, it was the top:auto style for the form that broke the button loose and put it down where it belonged. I wouldn't have expected this.  I know auto :"lets the browser calculate the margin" but my use of auto has been limited to centering things horizontally. Do you have any words on why the top:auto style for the form was so magical?     Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, I awarded the bounty prematurely before I checked out that answer, that turned out not to work for me.   Let me try to generate another bounty and give it to you.

Comment: @Steve Glad to hear that it worked. `auto` is just the default value for the properties `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right`. Since the `top` value was set to `top: 24px`, setting `auto` essentially overwrote it and set it back to the default. You could have also just removed it for the same effect.

Comment: Josh, I tried to create a new 50 pt bounty for you but because it's the second bounty for the question SO is forcing me to make it 200 pts or more and since I only have 258 points that wouldn't leave me anything to work with.  Sorry.  If you happen to answer any future questions for me I'll add the bounty.

Comment: @Steve It's fine -- I understand... I have enough rep anyways :p

Answer (score 2):

You have style for the form element

```
#checkout_form {
position: relative;
top: 24px;
left: 43px;
width: 224px;
display: inline;
}
```

`display:inline;` is what is causing the problem, and makes the button look like its floating. and not correctly rendered in safari. I dont know the cause of the issue in safari, but I have a workaround which works(I tried on on your website and it perfectly works on chrome and safari).

Change your markup a little, add a div tag inside the form to contain only the labels and the inputs but not the button you want to render on the next line.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="checkout_form" autocomplete="off">
    <div style="display: inline;">
          <label id="email">email</label> 
          <input type="email" size="20" id="checkout_form_email" class="email generic" placeholder="john@comcast.net" required="" autocomplete=""><br>

          <label id="phone">phone</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_phone" class="phone generic" placeholder="(209) 322-6046" autocomple="" required=""><br>

          <label id="name">name</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_name" class="name generic" placeholder="John Doe" autocomplete="" required=""><br>

          <label id="street">street</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_street" class="street generic" placeholder="123 Maple St." autocomplete="" required=""><br>

          <label id="city">city</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_city" class="city generic" placeholder="San Jose" autocomplete="" required=""><br>

          <label id="state">state</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_state" class="state generic" placeholder="NY" autocomplete="" required=""><br>

          <label id="cc">cc#</label>
          <input type="text" size="20" id="checkout_form_cc_number" class="cc-number" x-autocompletetype="cc-number" required=""><br>

          <label id="exp">exp</label>
          <input type="text" id="checkout_form_cc_exp" class="cc-exp" x-autocompletetype="cc-exp" placeholder="MM/YY" required="" maxlength="9">

          <label id="CVC">cvc</label>
          <input type="text" class="cc-cvc" x-autocompletetype="cc-csc" placeholder="CVC" required="" maxlength="4" autocomplete=""><br>

          <label id="instr">instr</label>
          <input type="text" id="instructions" placeholder="black"><br>
     </div>
          <div class="button" style="display: inline-block;">
               <div class="inner">
                 <button type="submit">
                       <span class="pay_amount">Pay $12.00</span>
                 </button>
               </div>
          </div>

          <img id="padlock" src="https://zackel.com/images/padlock_30.jpg" alt="padlock">
          <img id="creditcards" src="https://zackel.com/images/creditcards.jpg" alt="creditcards">
          <div id="validation"></div>

    </form>
```

I have wrapped your form with a `div` with style `display-inline`, 
and add a style `display:inline-block` to the `div` in which you have wrapped your button.

```
<div class="button" style="display: inline-block;">
                   <div class="inner">
                     <button type="submit">
                           <span class="pay_amount">Pay $12.00</span>
                     </button>
                   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remove the position relative css properties and add margin in your css.

**Previous code:** 

#checkout_form button {
    /* position:relative; */
    /* top:9px; */
    /* left:71px; */

    height:34px;
    width:180px;
/*  background-image:linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);  */
    border:none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /* blue gradient */
    background: #17b4e8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);/*For IE10*/
    background: linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);

}

**New css:**

#checkout_form button {


    height:34px;
    width:180px;
/*  background-image:linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);  */
    border:none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    /* blue gradient */
    background: #17b4e8;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);/*For IE10*/
    background: linear-gradient(#47baf5,#2378b3);
    margin: 9px 0 0 71px;
}
```